# wp_nav_menu including Skype URL

Tags: menus, urls, navigation

If I try to add a skype username as the URL for a wp_nav_menu item, the item is saved but the URL is not.

The username URL is in the following format:

skype:example?call

Any thoughts on add skype: as an acceptable protocol?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is concerning the menus under apperance > menu.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [`esc_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) function is what ultimately filters the url you enter in that field. Unfortunately, I don't see how you could allow the skype protocol without manually editing that function in the core file `wp-includes/formatting.php`, which is always a bad idea.

```
if ( !is_array($protocols) )
    $protocols = array ('http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'mailto', 'news', 'irc', 'gopher', 'nntp', 'feed', 'telnet', 'mms', 'rtsp', 'svn');
if ( wp_kses_bad_protocol( $url, $protocols ) != $url )
    return '';
```

Perhaps I've missed something though.

Comment: Hmm seems there is a filter, but it doesn't seem to work... apply_filters( 'kses_allowed_protocols', $protocols ) found that digging around wp_allowed_protocols()

Answer (score 1):

You can make the skype: as an acceptable protocol by adding the following code in the functions.php file of your child theme or develop a small plugin and add it in that plugin file.

```
/**
 * Allows users to save skype protocol skype: in menu URL
 */
function vvd_allow_skype_protocol( $protocols ){
    $protocols[] = 'skype';
    return $protocols;
}
add_filter( 'kses_allowed_protocols' , 'vvd_allow_skype_protocol' );
```